# Graphql exception handling not catching exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql, graphql-ruby

Sometimes exception handling works, and sometimes it does not. I will try to only show the smallest amount of relevant code:

app/graphql/dbz_schema.rb:

```
DbzSchema = GraphQL::Schema.define do
  mutation(Types::MutationType)
  query(Types::QueryType)
end
```

app/graphql/types/breed_type.rb:

```
Types::BreedType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  name "Breed"
  field :id, !types.ID
  field :name, !types.String
end
```

app/graphql/types/mutation_type.rb:

```
Types::MutationType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  name "Mutation"

  field :updateBreed, function: Resolvers::UpdateBreed.new
end
```

app/graphql/resolvers/update_breed.rb

```
class Resolvers::UpdateBreed < GraphQL::Function
  argument :name, !types.String
  argument :id, !types.ID

  type Types::BreedType

  def call(_obj, args, _ctx)
    Breed.update(args[:id], { name: args[:name] })

  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
    GraphQL::ExecutionError.new("Invalid input: #{e.record.errors.full_messages.join(', ')}")
  end
end
```

If I run the query:

```
mutation {
  updateBreed(id: 7, name: "Cat") {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

But the server log shows:

```
Started POST "/graphql" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-03 12:02:03 +0000
Processing by GraphqlController#execute as */*
  Parameters: {"query"=>"mutation {\n  updateBreed(id: 7, name: \"Cat\") {\n    id\n    name\n  }\n}", "variables"=>nil}}
  Breed Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "breeds".* FROM "breeds" WHERE "breeds"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 33ms (ActiveRecord: 3.7ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Breed with 'id'=7):

app/graphql/resolvers/update_breed.rb:8:in `call'
app/controllers/graphql_controller.rb:10:in `execute'
```

That clearly shows an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`, and I attempted to rescue that, but it is not working.

The chrome console shows:

`graphql Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`
`POST http://localhost:3000/graphql 404 (Not Found)`

It points to the following graphql javascript highlighting the 2nd line starting with `return`:

```
    function graphQLFetcher(graphQLParams) {
      return fetch(graphQLEndpoint, {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "X-CSRF-Token": "SWM3i9waP9i/sUMo1vcCg/9wdDRmPfkd99uuAKrIAEdz522ir1ildIccLpSDKhYE76cZgimk3IW5sXkOd0d3rQ=="
},
        body: JSON.stringify(graphQLParams),
        credentials: 'include',
      }).then(function (response) {
        return response.json()
      });
    }
```

Comment: Not  sure why it is not being handled but as a note `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` will not have `record` method meaning this `e.record.errors.full_messages.join(', ')` will fail because it looks like you are trying to handle an invalid update but in this case the record does not exist at all

Comment: So I actually figured it out just a tiny bit after posting, but you are on the money there. The exception is being handled...but then I'm firing a new exception because there is no `record` on `e`. Unfortunately, the error messages provided by graphql don't give any insight to this.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to achieve the same thing, with as minimal interference with defaults. I also wanted to avoid catching Exceptions as my code then becomes responsible for handling them appropriately :-)

Instead, I have discovered you can cast a route as being a JSON endpoint so it will cast the responses as JSON - including exceptions and errors:

For example, in my `routes.rb`:

```
  post '/graphql', to: 'graphql#execute', defaults: { format: :json }
```

This now results in a breaking GraphQL request response that is in JSON instead of HTML:

```
{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"}
```